# one size bigger

Tags: phrase-usage

I know the meaning of *one size fits all*, but this is the first time I've come across the expression one size bigger. By using Google I know that you could say *one size smaller*.

But I don't know exactly the function of ***one*** in "*one size*". For example, can I say:"Do you have these shoes ***two/three*** size bigger?"

I think I don't have to make *size* plural if *two/three* is added, don't I?

Comment: The answer can be found in special usage of certain adjectives. He is 12 years **old**. We are two players **short**. These pants are two sizes too **big**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "one" in "one size bigger" refers to the number of sizes bigger, in this case one. If you're holding a pair of size 11 shoes and you ask for the shoes "one size bigger", I would bring you a pair of size 12 shoes (11 + 1 = 12).

You can certainly say "two/three sizes bigger", in which cases "sizes" should be plural, since you're counting the number of sizes.

Since we're talking shoes, you can also say, "half a size bigger".

Comment: Also, let's not forget about how the Grinch's heart grew [three sizes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGSs33DQ1F0) that day.

Comment: "And what happened then? Well, in Whoville they say that the Grinch's small heart grew three sizes that day." Thanks @J.R. for the memory retention technique.